# Blend mode multiply with transparency on spritekit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, blending, skaction

I'm working with SpriteKit and I'm trying to make five nodes, with blend mode multiply, appear and disappear sequentially.

The problem I'm facing is that, when I call `SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(duration)` instead of fading out, the node turn black, as you can see in the image:

[image: Result]

But, if I call `SKAction.hide()` the node does hides (instantaneously), I'm confused on why these two functions have different results. My theory is that the `alpha` property of the node fill it with white color, instead of making it transparent (turning black with the multiply blend). How can I make the node properly hide in a given time?

FYI: This is not a game, it's a SKView inside of my UIKit-based app, I'm working with SpriteKit because I really need the multiply blend and animations.

Comment: hide is a boolean which determines weather the node should be drawn at all.

Comment: can you try `colorizeWithColor:colorBlendFactor:duration` with the node's color and zero alpha